# Vbscript to install Lastest Java Version

Tags: vbscript

I am attempting to automate the installation of Java for setting up new machines.
I plan to download java to a directory on the network and have the script pull the install from there.
I want the script to determine between 32bit and 64bit installers and not have to change the script everytime I download new installers.

How would I go about running the file path with wild cards?

Here is what I have so far

This determines the architecture

```
Function GetArch
Dim WshShell
Dim WshProcEnv
Dim system_architecture
Dim process_architecture

Set WshShell =  CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshProcEnv = WshShell.Environment("Process")

process_architecture= WshProcEnv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE") 

If process_architecture = "x86" Then    
    system_architecture= WshProcEnv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432")

    If system_architecture = ""  Then    
        system_architecture = "x86"
    End if    
Else    
    system_architecture = process_architecture    
End If

'WScript.Echo "Running as a " & process_architecture & " process on a " & system_architecture & " system."
GetArch = system_architecture
End Function
```

This runs the executable

```
Function runExec(strExec,blWait)
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
objShell.Run strExec, 1 ,blWait
Set objShell = Nothing
End Function
```

This will hopefully install Java

```
Function InstallJava
if Instr(1, GetArch, "64") then
    runExec "\\fs1\IT\Scripts\Java\jre-*-x64.exe",true
    InstallJava = "Java 64bit Installed"
ElseIf Instr(1, GetArch, "86") then
    runExec "\\fs1\IT\Scripts\Java\jre-*-i586.exe",true
    InstallJava = "Java 32bit Installed"
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcards are not supported. You need to enumerate the files, e.g. like this:

```vbs
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("\\fs1\IT\Scripts\Java").Files
  If LCase(Left(f.Name, 4)) = "jre-" Then
    If InStr(1, GetArch, "64") > 0 Then
      If LCase(Right(f.Name, 8)) = "-x64.exe" Then runExec f.Path, True
    ElseIf InStr(1, GetArch, "86") > 0 Then
      If LCase(Right(f.Name, 9)) = "-i586.exe" Then runExec f.Path, True
    End If
  End If
Next
```

You could use a different approach, though. Since you're going to download and provide the files on a share, you could modify the provisioning to create/update a symbolic link with a fixed name to the respective files, e.g.

```
D:\IT\Scripts\Java>mklink jre-CURRENT-x64.exe jre-7u45-windows-x64.exe
D:\IT\Scripts\Java>mklink jre-CURRENT-x86.exe jre-7u45-windows-i586.exe
```

and then use those fixed names in your install script:

```vbs
If Instr(1, GetArch, "64") > 0 then
  runExec "\\fs1\IT\Scripts\Java\jre-CURRENT-x64.exe", True
ElseIf Instr(1, GetArch, "86") > 0 then
  runExec "\\fs1\IT\Scripts\Java\jre-CURRENT-x86.exe", True
End If
```